# how to write the sql code to get the data between 2 dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction date and I want to get the data from the latest effective date that less or equal to transaction date.

Here is the table i have

```
transactiondate|effectivedate|unitprice
19-02-19       |01-01-19     | 36
19-02-19       |28-12-18     | 30
19-02-19       |15-12-18     | 20
```

Here is the query I used

```
select A.unitprice, A.transactiondate, A.effectivedate
from A
where A.transactiondate >= A.effectivedate
```

and here is the result I got

```
transactiondate|effectivedate|unitprice
19-02-19       |01-01-19     | 36
19-02-19       |28-12-18     | 30
19-02-19       |15-12-18     | 20
```

But I want to get this data

```
transactiondate|effectivedate|unitprice
19-02-19       |01-01-19     | 36
```

I use My SQL server. Please help me to correct the query to get the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
select A.unitprice, A.transactiondate, A.effectivedate
from A
where A.effectivedate = (select max(effectivedate) from A)
and A.effectivedate <= A.transactiondate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your dates are not in a MySQL recognised date format, so you need to convert them to compare them. You also need to find the maximum effectivedate to compare against:

```
SELECT A.unitprice, A.transactiondate, A.effectivedate
FROM A
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(A.effectivedate, '%d-%m-%y') =
  (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(effectivedate, '%d-%m-%y'))
   FROM A
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(A.transactiondate, '%d-%m-%y') >= STR_TO_DATE(A.effectivedate, '%d-%m-%y'))
  AND STR_TO_DATE(A.transactiondate, '%d-%m-%y') >= STR_TO_DATE(A.effectivedate, '%d-%m-%y');
```

Output:

```
unitprice   transactiondate effectivedate
36          19-02-19        01-01-19
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gdaE3zvbo7kCEMXW7WMKu2/0)

Comment: OP says it's ms sql sever - STR_TO_DATE() will not work

Comment: OP clearly states "My SQL Server" and has tagged question `mysql`, not `sql-server`

Comment: @fa06 no problems. It is an unusual way of writing MySQL

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the max of effectivedate by transactiondate and then use that to get the result.

Try following query

```
SELECT a.* FROM tran_date a INNER JOIN(
    SELECT transactiondate, 
    MAX(effectivedate) AS max_date 
    FROM tran_date WHERE transactiondate > effectivedate 
    GROUP BY transactiondate
) AS b 
ON a.transactiondate = b.transactiondate 
AND a.effectivedate = b.max_date
```

Here , inner query return you the max effectivedate by transactiondate and then use that result with outer query

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LRFb2Yt5gWjuHg36NrJ86/0)

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select transactiondate,min(effectivedate) latest_date,unitprice 
from Table1;
```

check this:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc3fc/9

Comment: How can a `min` function give you the maximum (latest) value of a date?